# opencv.hpp is not found when compiling with makefile in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, gnu-make

I am new to C++ and trying to compile my project with a Makefile. I have three files: main.cpp, FrameDifference.cpp and FrameDifference.hpp. The main.cpp uses methods from the FrameDifference.cpp

However, my Makefile seems wrong since my code does not compile.

> 

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags opencv4)
LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs opencv4)
OBJFILES = FrameDifference.o main.o
TARGET = output

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJFILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJFILES) $(TARGET) *~
```

Error message:

```
g++    -c -o FrameDifference.o FrameDifference.cpp
FrameDifference.cpp:4:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
    4 | #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: FrameDifference.o] Error 1
```

I already tried to change the CFLAGS and the LIBS but it seems not to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily see from the command line make is invoking that your flags are not being used:

```
g++    -c -o FrameDifference.o FrameDifference.cpp
```

You are setting `CFLAGS`, which is the variable that holds flags for invoking the C compiler in the built-in rules for make.

But, you are not compiling C code, you're compiling C++ code, so the `CFLAGS` variable is not used.

If you are compiling C++ code, you want to set the `CXXFLAGS` variable which holds flags for the C++ compiler in the built-in rules for make.